# Show different home page based on user role

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show different homepages based on the user role. I have 4 differents pages:

Home - Default one
Home 1 - User role 1
Home 2 - User role 2
Home 3 - User role 3

The problem i have right now is to show the pages for the user roles.

This is the function i'm using for check the user role.

```
function get_user_role(){
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        global $current_user;
        $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
        $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
        return $user_role;
    }else{
        return "subscriber";
   } 
}
```

Also i'm showing the page called "Home" to show on homepage using in the page.php

```
is_front_page()
```

But.. How can i show the other pages instead of the default front page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just include different scripts for the different role. Then you can code one script per "home page".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `get_template_part()` function:

```
get_template_part('home', get_user_role());
```

Using WordPress’s template hierarchy, if the current user’s role was Administrator then the template would first look for **home-administrator.php**, and if that was not found then it would just fall back to **home.php**.

Comment: But the problem with get_template_part() i can't get the specific page that i created with wordpress.
I want to show for each role and specific wordpress page on the front page

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. You would use `get_template_part()` get get a template to use as your home page based on the user role.

Answer (score 0):

First set the (static) front page to a default setting, then use the [option filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/option_(option_name)) to override the setting depending on the user.

```
add_filter('option_page_on_front', 'your_override_function');
function your_override_function($page_id) {
   if (get_user_role == 'some_value') {
      return some_page_id;
   }
   return $page_id;
}
```