# Different front pages by User role

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to set the wordpress home page (front page) by user role

example case 1. role admin --> homepage A
             2. role seller --> homepage B

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show different home page based on user role](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288889/show-different-home-page-based-on-user-role)

Answer (score 1):

You can select your page as your front page and inside that page your can apply checks to show data to relevant user role. For example,

```
<?php if(role == 'admin'){?>
//show this part to admin
<?php } else if(role == 'user'){?>
//show this part to user .... etc
<?php } ?>
```

This is just for example purposes, inside if else conditions you will apply your proper code to check your user roles and will be providing your desired data which you want to show. Hope that makes sense.

For checking user roles here is one nice forum post https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-users-role